# nodeJS async each, function has another argument

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Hi I have array of domains.
For each domain I need to run

```
s3.listObjects(since, domain, callback);
```

using `async.each` how can I pass since argument there ?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: async.each on an array like [{ "since": "something", "domain": "something" }]